# Find earliest due date on Excel Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multipage userform with each tab containing details on a separate task that is to be completed. Each task has a different due date based on the expiry date of the client's policy.

I've used an IF statement to determine which task is due next. This has worked fine until now, but there are now multiple situations where one or more of the tasks are due earlier than originally anticipated which of course is not returning the accurate next due items.

*e.g. The cQteSlipDue date in my below code is the strRnl (renewal date) less 60 days and the cClaimsDue is less 45 days, however now in some circumstances the cClaimsDue is less 75 days, meaning it is due before the cQteSlipDue.*

Is there a way for me to determine the earliest occurring date with an Array?
FYI - The "dates" in my sheet are actually text strings as I couldn't get UK (dd-mm-yyyy) formatting to work consistently any other way.

My current code is below for reference:

````
Sub Int_Dash_NxtDue()

Dim cClient As String: cClient = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "E")
Dim cRenDate As String: cRenDate = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F")
Dim strRnl As String: strRnl = Format(DateAdd("d", 0, CDate(cRenDate)), "[$-en-UK}]dd-mm-yyyy")

Dim str45 As String
    If InStr(cClient, "(APEX)") Then
        str45 = Format(DateAdd("d", -75, CDate(strRnl)), "[$-en-UK}]dd-mm-yyyy")
    Else
        str45 = Format(DateAdd("d", -45, CDate(strRnl)), "[$-en-UK}]dd-mm-yyyy")
    End If

'Pre-Renewal
Dim cPreRenDue As String: cPreRenDue = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "R")
Dim cPreRenDone As String: cPreRenDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "S")
Dim cClaimsDue As String: cClaimsDue = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "U")
Dim cClaimsRDone As String: cClaimsRDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "V")
Dim cClaimsDone As String: cClaimsDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "W")
Dim cQteSlipDue As String: cQteSlipDue = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "Y")
Dim cQteSlipDone As String: cQteSlipDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "Z")
Dim cDloadDue As String: cDloadDue = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AC")
Dim cDloadDone As String: cDloadDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AD")
'Renewal Report
Dim cRenRptDue As String: cRenRptDue = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AN")
Dim cRenRptDone As String: cRenRptDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AO")
Dim cTskRptType As String: cTskRptType = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AQ")
'Invoice
Dim cInvReq As String: cInvReq = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "BF")
Dim cInvDone As String: cInvDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "BM")
'Policy Schedule
Dim cPolDocReq As String: cPolDocReq = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "BV")
Dim cPolDocDone As String: cPolDocDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "CH")
'Insurance Manual
Dim cInsManReq As String: cInsManReq = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "CI")
Dim cInsManDone As String: cInsManDone = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "CK")
Dim cInsManDue As String: cInsManDue = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "CJ")
'Ren Rpt #1 done
Dim cTskRpt1Done As String: cTskRpt1Done = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "CP")

Dim strNxtTask As String, strNxtDue As String


If cPreRenDue <> "" And cPreRenDone = "" Then
    strNxtTask = "Pre-Renewal Pack"
    strNxtDue = cPreRenDue
Else
    If cTskRptType <> "" And cRenRptDue = "" And cTskRpt1Done = "" Then
        strNxtTask = "Draft Renewal Report #1"
        strNxtDue = cPreRenDue
    Else
        If cQteSlipDue <> "" And cQteSlipDone = "" Then
            strNxtTask = "Draft Quote Slips"
            strNxtDue = cQteSlipDue
        Else
            If cClaimsDue <> "" And cClaimsRDone = "" Then
                strNxtTask = "Request updated claims from UW"
                strNxtDue = str45
            Else
                If cClaimsDue <> "" And cClaimsDone = "" Then
                    strNxtTask = "Save updated claims to file"
                    strNxtDue = cClaimsDue
                Else
                    If cDloadDue <> "" And cDloadDone = "" Then
                        strNxtTask = "Download Terms"
                        strNxtDue = cDloadDue
                    Else
                        If cRenRptDue <> "" And cRenRptDone = "" Then
                            strNxtTask = "Draft Renewal Report"
                            strNxtDue = cRenRptDue
                        Else
                            If cInvReq <> "" And cInvDone = "" Then
                                strNxtTask = "Invoicing"
                                strNxtDue = LblInvDue.Caption
                            Else
                                If cPolDocReq <> "" And cPolDocDone = "" Then
                                    strNxtTask = "Check Policy Schedule Task"
                                    strNxtDue = LblPolDocDue.Caption
                                Else
                                    If cInsManReq <> "" And cInsManDone = "" Then
                                        strNxtTask = "Draft Insurance Manual"
                                        strNxtDue = cInsManDue
                                    Else
                                        strNxtTask = "Nil in Progress"
                                        strNxtDue = ""
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                       End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

LblNxtDue.Caption = strNxtDue
LblNxtTask.Caption = strNxtTask
End Sub```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ms5W.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not the answer you are looking for.  This is very difficult to visualize your problem from looking at the codes. But I think I got it.  You need to tell what the next task is and when it is due.

The str45 due date is the problem.  It is not a fixed due day.  After the calculation, this due date may be way ahead of the cQteSlipDue due dates.

```
If cClaimsDue <> "" And cClaimsRDone = "" Then
    strNxtTask = "Request updated claims from UW"
    strNxtDue = str45
Else
```

This is just my guess.  You will need to figure out if this is correct or not.  Why don't you assign the **Request updated claims form UW** task and the **str45** due date to another variables.  Maybe call them **strNxtTask2** and **strNxtDue2**.

```
If cClaimsDue <> "" And cClaimsRDone = "" Then
    strNxtTask2 = "Request updated claims from UW"
    strNxtDue2 = str45
Else
```

And then at the bottom, you compare strNxtDue2 and cQteSlipDue to see which one is ahead and re-assign strNxtDue to the date that is earlier.

```
if strNxtDue2 <= cQteSlipDue then
   strNxtDue = strNxtDue2
   strNxtTask = strNxtTask2
end if
```

Please let me know if I understand your problem correctly.